# Google Firebase Cloud Storage high bandwidth cost

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

The problem I'm experiencing is high cost of bandwidth usage on a multi regional us bucket. Can anyone explain what this cost corresponds to? This Firebase Storage service is used for hosting asset files therefore the only operation that is required by the end user is downloading.

Additionally cost for Upload ops/Download ops/Bytes stored are practically non existent from what I see in Firebase Console.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for a higher cost was that I had my assets stored in an additional bucket that I've created aside of the default one. As it turns out when you're utilizing additional buckets the different pricing schema is applied. Brief information in this regards can be found in Firebase pricing [page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) under **?** icon corresponding to Firebase Storage entry.

> This is the estimated pricing for common usage. Firebase Storage free
> limits are enforced daily and refreshed at midnight Pacific Time. In
> the Blaze plan, fees for Firebase Storage are based on usage volume.
> Firebase Storage usage fees are processed as Google Cloud App Engine
> usage fees for the default bucket, and Google Cloud Storage usage fees
> for any additional buckets. For more information, see pricing for
> Google Cloud App Engine and Storage.

Additionally, prior to my current implementation of assets cloud fetching, I had it done via publicly accessible HTTP protocol (there are many Youtube clips which "teach" this approach). I'm not quite sure but that might've had an impact on a pricing schema as well (it's a little bit too convoluted reading Google's documentation in this regards and understanding all the terminology). On top of that this approach presented security threat as the urls were publicly accessible to anyone - in order to prevent it one should always think of some kind of authorization mechanism.